# Stoke's Theorem to evaluate line integral of cylinder-plane intersection

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I want to use Stokes' Theorem to evaluate the line integral $F\cdot dr$

$F = (-y^2, x, z^2)$ and $C$ is the curve of the intersection of the plane 
$y+z=2$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$. $C$ should be oriented anticlockwise when viewed from above.

I am completely lost as to how to solve this. Im not even sure how to solve the line integral. Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Stokes, 
$$
\int_C F\cdot dr=\int\!\!\!\int_S\text{curl} F\cdot dS,
$$
where $S$ is a surface that has $C$ as boundary.

The advantage here is that 
$$
\text{curl}\,F=\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k\\ D_x& D_y& D_z\\-y^2&x&z^2\end{vmatrix}
=(0,0,1+2y)
$$
is simple.

If we take $S$ as the disc in the plane $y+z=2$ and bounded by the cylinder, we can parametrize it by 
$$
u(r,t)=(r\cos t, r\sin t, 2-r\sin t),\ \ 0\leq r\leq1,\ 0\leq t\leq 2\pi.
$$
Then normal vector is 
$$
u_r\times u_t=\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k\\ \cos t& \sin t& -\sin t\\ -r \sin t& r\cos t&-r\cos t\end{vmatrix}
=(0,r,r).
$$
Then
$$
\int_C F\cdot dr=\int\!\!\!\int_S\text{curl} F\cdot dS
=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}(0,0,1+2r\sin t)\cdot(0,r,r)\,dt\,dr\\
=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}(r+2r^2\sin t)\,dt\,dr
=\int_0^12\pi r\,dr=\pi.
$$

---

In this case, it is also easy to solve the line integral directly: using the parametrization $c(t)=(\cos t, \sin t,2-\sin t)$, $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$, we get
$$
\int_C F\cdot dr=\int_0^{2\pi}(-\sin^2t,\cos t,(2-\sin t)^2)\cdot(-\sin t,\cos t,-\cos t)\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}(-\sin^3t+\cos^2 t-(2-\sin t)^2\cos t )\,dt=\pi.
$$

Comment: How did you write dS=drdt? In case of polar coordinates, dS=dxdy=rdrdt

Comment: I didn't "write $dS=dr\,dt$". A surface integral is calculated like that, in terms of a parametrization of the surface.

Comment: But the parameterization you've done is basically turning it into polar coordinates. And differential area element in polar coordinates has to be rdrdt. I'm confused.. Also, instead of normal vector, aren't we supposed to use unit normal vector?

Comment: Again, that's how a surface integral (a flux, more properly) [is calculated](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_vector_fields). In a sense, the normalization of the normal is cancelled by the "change of variable". This is one of many examples where thinking "the physicist way" in terms of differentials is not a good idea.

Comment: Very nicely explained. Thank you for the nice insights.

Comment: Glad to hear! $ $